# What is the largest possible relation on set?

Tags: relations

I know, that

The smallest possible reflexive relation on a non-empty set is the ***diagonal ordered pairs of Cartesian product***.

The largest possible reflexive relation on a non-empty set is the ***entire Cartesian product***.

Likewise, The smallest possible anti-symmetric relation on a non-empty set is a ***null set***.

But, I am not able to discern...

> **The largest possible anti-symmetric relation on a non-empty set?**

P.S. I am not asking about- Total number of possible anti-symmetric relation.

Comment: Maximal partial orders on a set $S$ are not unique unless $S$ has $\leq 1$ element (take the opposite ordering, for example), so no "the largest".

Comment: @user10354138 your comment suffice my need. Yep, there doesn't exist unique largest subset of Cartesian product of give set that represent it.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A=\{1,2,3\}$. Then both $R=\{(1,1)\}$ and $S=\{(1,2), (1,3)\}$ are anti-symmetric but $R \not\subset S$ and $S \not\subset R$. So no largest anti-symmetric relation can exist.

Comment: The reason $R \not \subset S$ and $S \not \subset R$ is because there's a bigger antisymmetric relation than that, I think, unless I misunderstood something (per my own answer). Granted there is no singular "unique" antisymmetric relation, but we can at least quantify the number of such relations and even offer nice-looking samples (again, if my own understanding is correct).

Comment: @EeveeTrainer OP doesn't want the number of such relations as stated in the question.

Comment: Relation S **can also contain** all reflexive pairs and in that case R will be proper subset of S.

Comment: @Ubihatt The point is that the "largest" set having a property is the one that has all the sets with that same property **as it's subsets** which cannot happen here. Perhaps this example can help you. Consider $R=\{(1,2)\}$ and $S=\{(2,1)\}$, then both are anti-symmetric but cannot be subsets of each other.